# Load and execute javascript from body

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have the following code posted in the body (from the admin interface)

```
    <div class="zx_ABCD zx_mediaslot">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._zx = window._zx || [];
            window._zx.push({"id":"ABCD"});
            (function(d) { 
                var s = d.createElement("script"); s.async = true;
                s.src = (d.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//static.zanox.com/scripts/zanox.js";
                var a = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; a.parentNode.insertBefore(s, a);
            }(document));
        </script>
    </div>
```

I wonder why the code gets loaded correctly(can see it from the source) but it's not executed ?

Do you have any suggestions on workarounds for this?
(Is it a feasible solution to put the script inside an js file? can that be loaded from the body?)

I would like to be able to do this without having to touch the wordpress configuration/php.

Just from the admin interface

Cheers

Comment: Maybe the DOM isn't `.ready()` yet. Also you should properly register/enqueue the scripts (see `wp_enqueue_script()` in codex).

Comment: If you see the script in the source, then there is a problem with your code, you should post it.

Comment: @Wyck the code is ok since it works in normal pages (added inside the body), the problem only verifies with WP.

Comment: As per the WPSE FAQ, questions are not in our scope merely because they happen in the context of WordPress.

Comment: I understand, but since this snippet works in other context, I thought that it may be wordpress related, and maybe someone that had a similar issue could help me with that.